# Angular template not displaying the service file data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-templates

The template file is not displaying the data from the service file, can someone please check the code and correct me. Thank you.

Also I checked if data is passed by controller, which is happening. But nothing is displaying except for index. I tried data binding in several ways still problem seems to repeat.

---

**html**

```
<div class="panel3 panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Documents</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">

        <tr>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Document Type</th>
            <th>Document Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Last Update Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="file in selectedDoc">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{file.id.s.documentType}}</td>
            <td>{{file.id.s.documentDate}}</td>
            <td>{{file.id.s.status}}</td>
            <td>{{file.id.s.lastUpdateDate}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

---

**controller**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetDocumentsModule").controller("fleetDocumentsController",
    ['$scope', 'fleetDocumentsService',

        function ($scope, fleetDocumentsService) {


            $scope.selectedDoc = fleetDocumentsService.getDocuments();
            console.log("inside service file", $scope.selectedDoc)
        }]);
```

---

**service file**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetDocumentsModule").service("fleetDocumentsService",

       function () {
           this.getDocuments = function () {
               return documents;
           };
           var documents = [
               {
                   "id": "1",
                   "s":[{                         
                           "documentType": 'POD',
                           "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                           "status": 'Printed',
                           "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                       },
                   {                       
                           "documentType": 'SIM',
                   "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                   "status": 'Printed',
                   "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
               }                      
              ]},
                   {
                       "id": "2",                      
                       "s": [{
                            "documentType": 'DOC',
                            "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                            "status": 'Printed',
                            "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                        },
                    {
                        "documentType": 'LLTM',
                        "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                        "status": 'Printed',
                        "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                    }
                       ]},                   
                   {
                       "id": "3",                     
                       "s": [{
                           "documentType": 'TOM2',
                           "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                           "status": 'Printed',
                           "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                       },
                       {
                           "documentType": 'TOM3',
                           "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                           "status": 'Printed',
                           "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                       },
                   {
                       "documentType": 'TOM4',
                       "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                       "status": 'Printed',
                       "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
                   }
                       ]},
           {
               "id": "4",
               "s":[{
                   "documentType": 'TTL',
                   "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
                   "status": 'Recieved',
                   "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
               }],
           },
           {
               "id": "5",
               "s":[{
               "documentType": 'RET',
               "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
               "status": 'Printed',
               "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
               }],
           }
           ]});
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using correct properties in view for each object

Property `file.s` is array not object and there is no `file.id.s`

Try changing:

```
{{file.id.s.documentType}}
```

To

```
{{file.s[0].documentType}}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4kf4jjDkcYfXvUn0Kpe4)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, ok its calling, but its not calling everything that needs to be displayed under "id":"1".

For example: in id:1 it has to display all 2 objects. In id:3, display all 3 objects

Comment: ok if you notice in the browser, only the first set of data in each "s" array is displayed. How do I make all the data in that array get displayed?

Comment: Suggest you map data to flatter array...or `ng-repeat` on `<tbody>` and then `ng-repeat` rows for each `s`   Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rnZvhPnocuU2HrrTvBl6

Answer (score 0):

Hi the error is from the way you reference the object. Your object structure is this:

```
{
           "id": "4",
           "s":[{
               "documentType": 'TTL',
               "documentDate": '01-12-2015',
               "status": 'Recieved',
               "lastUpdateDate": '28-12-2015'
           }],
       }
```

while you try to reference it this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in selectedDoc">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{file.id.s.documentType}}</td>
        <td>{{file.id.s.documentDate}}</td>
        <td>{{file.id.s.status}}</td>
        <td>{{file.id.s.lastUpdateDate}}</td>
    </tr>
```

instead of this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in selectedDoc">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{file.s[0].documentType}}</td>
        <td>{{file.s[0].documentDate}}</td>
        <td>{{file.s[0].status}}</td>
        <td>{{file.s[0].lastUpdateDate}}</td>
    </tr>
```

you don't need the `id` part.
Hope that fixes it!

Comment: property `s` is array though, so it has no object properties

Comment: Thanx. I just noticed that. And your answer too